# Android - How to move to activity dynamically or previous activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have 3 activities , Activity A and Activity B both can access to Activity C.
But at a time,I am using Intent to return back to previous activity.

Intent i = new Intent(C.this , A.class);

Here i use activity C to return back to Activity A.
but i want to return to activity A or B from C depending upon who called it.
Not using finish(); to return back to activity.

If A calls C then `intent i = new Intent (C.this, "dynamically set A");`

If B calls C then `intent i = new Intent (C.this, "dynamically set B");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a bundle in first call(A to C or B to C) and check where it's came from when clicking back action.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use finish() method without using the intent. Look at this:

```
Button button = this.findViewById(R.id.backButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
  }
});
```

Comment: i do not want to finish the activity to return to previous, any other alternative